# how can i solve this problem PHP can any one help me

Tags: php

```php
<body>   
    <?php
        $t1= $_POST['t1'];
        $t2= $_POST['t2'];

        $datetime1 = new DateTime($t1);//start time
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($t2);//end time
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        echo $interval->format('%Y years %m months %d days %H hours %i minutes %s seconds');//00 years 0 months 0 days 08 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
        // put your code here
        ?>
    <input type="time" name="t1">
    <input type="time" name="t2">    
</body>
```

```
Warning: Undefined array key "t1" in D:\xampp\htdocs\ITC\index.php on line 14
Warning: Undefined array key "t2" in D:\xampp\htdocs\ITC\index.php on line 15 00 years 0 months 0 days 00 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
```

Comment: You are using variables in the `$_POST` array without checking whether they exist or not. If this is a form submission, check that the form has been submitted before using the form variables (using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"`), if not then use `isset()` or similar to check each variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help but still i  have  the same Error

Comment: Show us how you've tried to fix it. Edit your code above so we can see what you've done. If you check correctly whether the array elements exist before you try to use them (and don't use them if they don't), I can't see how you can possibly get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two  element inside a form with method="post"

Like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="time" name="t1">
    <input type="time" name="t2">
    </form>
```

Comment: `    <form action="$_POST" action="#">
    <input type="time" name="t1">
    <input type="time" name="t2">
     </form>`